# MySQL query to return only duplicate entries with counts

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a legacy MySQL table called `lnk_lists_addresses` with columns `list_id` and `address_id`. I'd like to write a query that reports all the cases where the same `list_id`-`address_id` combination appears more than once in the table with a count.

I tried this...

```
SELECT count(*), list_id, address_id
FROM lnk_lists_addresses
GROUP BY list_id, address_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

It works, sort of, because there are fewer than 20 duplicates. But how would I return only the counts greater than 1?

I tried adding "`WHERE count(*) > 1`" before and after `GROUP BY` but got errors saying the statement was invalid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*), list_id, address_id
FROM lnk_lists_addresses
GROUP BY list_id, address_id
HAVING count(*)>1
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

To combine mine and Todd.Run's answers for a more "complete" answer.  You want to use the HAVING clause:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a "HAVING" clause. Its use is explained in the MySQL manual.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) AS total, list_id, address_id
FROM lnk_lists_addresses
WHERE total > 1
GROUP BY list_id, address_id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 20
```

If you name the COUNT() field, you can use it later in the statement.

EDIT: forgot about `HAVING` (>_<)